# Regex to remove control characters except in a certain tag

Tags: java, regex

I am removing control characters from a string as I load and deserialise it.
I do this with the following regex, which is fine:

```
\\p{C}
```

The issue is part of the text is meant to have new lines in it. So what I need to do is remove all control characters **unless** they fall between `<Text>` and `</Text>`.

How can do I do this with a regex?

Comment: Not easily; you should consider a more sophisticated solution; I happen to have [a project which could help you there](https://github.com/parboiled1/grappa)

Comment: Or else, well, your input seems to be XML so why not use a streaming XML parser API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
replaceAll("(?s)(<Text>.*?</Text>)|\\p{C}", "$1")
```

The idea is to skip `Text` tags contents and leave them alone (replace them with themselves). So if we encounter a `\\p{C}`, we know it's not inside one.

**Explanation**:

- `(?s)` activates "dot match all", so `.` will match newline as well
- `(<Text>.*?</Text>)` *captures* the text node in the first group. We replace with the result of this capture through `$1`
- If we match `\\p{C}`, this means we are not in a Text node. So we replace with `$1`, which is empty since `(<Text>.*?</Text>)` didn't match in the alternation.

Ideone illustration: http://ideone.com/xKZgsn

Comment: As an optional minor tweak, `[^<]*<` is more efficient than `.*?<`

Comment: @zx81: I was going to link to the [Match a pattern except in three situations s1, s2, s3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-a-pattern-except-in-three-situations-s1-s2-s3) answer, then I realized you wrote it :)

Comment: I think this is removing both the control characters and the entire Text tags. Have I misunderstood how you are suggesting I use this?

Comment: @zx81: It is, but I don't know whether there are other tags nested inside the `<Text>` one.

Comment: Ha, small world, and yeah, good point!... Scrap that thought. :)

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying and based on that it seems like it should work, but when I actually use it on my string it removes bothe the control characters AND the text tags and everything inside.

Comment: @DavidKibblewhite Did you replace with `$1`? [See example with digits](http://fiddle.re/ebkcp) (click on "Java" -> replaceAll section) works fine for me.

Comment: Ah I see what's happening now. Your regex replaces any control characters with "null", rather than "", which is what it really needs to be.

Comment: Accepted your answer, since anything still wrong is a separate issue for me to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex :

```
/(?!<text[^>]*?>)(\p{C}+)(?![^<]*?<\/text>)/gi
```

But, as mentioned by @fge, would be better to cleanly parse your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a string I have to test regex patterns that remove control characters.

> AAU?Aasddsaustw3h,kdf134dfswdesdfent?�sdfsadfa45678r?w3h,kdf134dfswdesdfawh,kdf134dfswdesdfsurew3h,kdf134dfswdesdfent??3asdfliit/123423defwecty   ?�STasd?Pawh,kdf134dfswdesdfks?Hw3rsdfsd134dfswdet

It seems regex pattern `"[[:cntrl:]]"` works well.
`string.replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", "")` just replace part of them.
`"\p{Cntrl}"` just replace empty string after "wecty".

Can anyone told me what's those control characters are? I can replace them but could not figure out what are they.
The jave online regex test show there are 11 control characters matched.
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output